# Classification of discontinuities of multidimensional maps

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, notation

I know that for functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ there exist references which describe various discontinuities that these functions can exhibit. However, I could never find any source of information that would present a unified approach to the classification of the discontinuities of more general functions (for example, $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or, at least $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$). It would also be useful to know if there exists standard notation for some of the discontinuities that occur in such functions.

Comment: Functions of the form $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are curves, and their discontinuity points are treated exactly as in the easy case $\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, since $f = (f_1, \dots , f_n)$ is continuous iff all the $f_i$ are. On the contrary, functions of the form $f:\mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can present different species of discontinuity... But I don't think there is a name or a classification of them.

Comment: Choose any set $A$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f$ is discontinuous on the boundary of $A$. Classification of discontinuities would be equivalent to the classification of boundaries.

Comment: "[With functions of two or more variables, however, no simple discontinuity classification is possible.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Discontinuity.html) There are a number of caveats which hinder any classification of the discontinuities of multivariate functions, chief among which is the fact that multivariate functions need neither jump nor "blow up" at points of discontinuity (Lady 1998). . . ." "[In general, one generally does not classify discontinuities quite so closely \[as in the real case\], since they can have quite complicated behaviour.](http://planetmath.org/discontinuous)"

Comment: More mathematically useful is classifying the various types of limits, since this is what really tells you about the local behavior, not continuity (which only adds the value at the point as a requirement). Some terms to google: "radial limit", nontangential limit", "stolz angle limit". By the way, I'm rather surprised someone didn't mention this when the question originally appeared, as these notions are extremely well known in many areas of contemporary research (complex analysis, harmonic analysis, partial differential equations, etc.)